# No POST requests shown in Symfony Profiler

Tags: symfony

Strange thing happend to me, since this morning I can't see any post requests in symfony profiler. Only the GET requests are shown there.

[image: print screen]

However at the profiler bar I can see that the POST request has been provided.
[image]

I've tried to update to version 3.3.0 and cleared all caches but got the same issue. Any ideas?

Comment: I see in your `Results` list you are only selecting "10". What if you increase that to "100"?

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue

Comment: And you are certain you've sent a recent POST and you've checked you apache logs to verify the request came in?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what happened, but here is the solution that worked for me. Since I'm using Homestead with Nginx, I was looking for some irregularities in host config file. So I found one and replaced this line:

> try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;

to this:

> try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php?$query_string;

The strange thing is that yesterday everything was working well, and I'm pretty sure that I wasn't tweaking nginx config file for at least 2 months. So be it, the issue is solved.